# How do I remove spacing around elements inside ".container-fluid"?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Here I'm creating a header with `display: flex;` for perfect horizontally centering my elements inside that and not vertically centering them. Without using Bootstrap, everything works right, but as soon as I add Bootstrap CSS to my HTML, they just leap into the center of  the `.container` with a little spacing between them, I want my `.right-svg` and `.nike-svg` to be placed at the very right and left spaces in their `.container`.

NOTE: The result f this snippet is exactly what I want it to look like, but please add Bootstrap CSS 3 to this HTML as I did, and the problem will be shown.
Any advises is welcome.

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
main{
    max-width: 100%;
}

/*======================   header  ======================*/
header .row{
    margin: 0;
}
header .row .col-xs-12{
    padding: 0;
}
header .row .gen-nav-header{
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #e38d13;
}
header .row .gen-nav-header .container-fluid{
    width: 96%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    display: flex;
    /*align-items: center;*/
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
header .row .gen-nav-header .container-fluid .right-svg{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
    align-items: center;
    border: 1px solid #000;

    flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
header .row .gen-nav-header .container-fluid .nike-svg{
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Nike Official Site. Nike DE</title>
</head>
href="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/nike-icon.jpg">
<body>
<main>
<!-- ================  header  ============== -->
    <header>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div class="gen-nav-header">
                    <div class="container-fluid">

    <!------------------  right svg   ------------------->
                        <div class="right-svg">
                            <span class="hamburger-menu-svg">
                            <svg width="24px" height="24px" fill="#111" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M21 13H3c-.6 0-1-.4-1-1s.4-1 1-1h18c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1zm0-8H3c-.6 0-1-.4-1-1s.4-1 1-1h18c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1zm0 16H3c-.6 0-1-.4-1-1s.4-1 1-1h18c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1z"></path></svg>
                        </span>
                            <span class="search-svg">
                            <svg class="pre-search-input-icon" fill="#111" height="30px" width="30px" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M21.71 20.29L18 16.61A9 9 0 1 0 16.61 18l3.68 3.68a1 1 0 0 0 1.42 0 1 1 0 0 0 0-1.39zM11 18a7 7 0 1 1 7-7 7 7 0 0 1-7 7z"></path></svg>
                        </span>
                            <span class="shopping-svg">
                            <svg width="24px" height="24px" fill="#111" viewBox="0 0 24 24"><path d="M16 7a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V3H9v3a1 1 0 0 1-2 0V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h6a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1z"></path><path d="M20 5H4a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v13a3 3 0 0 0 3 3h14a3 3 0 0 0 3-3V7a2 2 0 0 0-2-2zm0 15a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V7h16z"></path></svg>
                        </span>
                        </div>
<!-----------------   end right svg   ------------------->

                        <span class="nike-svg">
                            <svg class="pre-logo-svg" height="60px" width="60px" fill="#111" viewBox="0 0 69 32"><path d="M68.56 4L18.4 25.36Q12.16 28 7.92 28q-4.8 0-6.96-3.36-1.36-2.16-.8-5.48t2.96-7.08q2-3.04 6.56-8-1.6 2.56-2.24 5.28-1.2 5.12 2.16 7.52Q11.2 18 14 18q2.24 0 5.04-.72z"></path></svg>
                        </span>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

</main>
<script src="node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Here is the image from that website: https://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_58937/images/index-01.jpg

Comment: Wow, thanks! I wish I could learn from you how you did that.

Comment: You can simply get it from developer tools. Locate the image in the code and copy the URL.

Comment: Do you want any other image?

Comment: Still trying to find one image URL in the code in Devtools, but I can't find one. Could you take a screenshot of the location of the URL you gave me please?

Comment: Which one?.....

Comment: Can you tell how do you find them?

Comment: The URL image you first commented here.

Comment: https://livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_58937/images/index-01.jpg

Comment: ScreenShot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfvZY.png

Comment: So how did you add that prefix to the address as "livedemo00.template-help.com/wt_58937/" ?

Comment: with the help of computed value

Comment: I kindly need a little more help with this if you don't mind, this is my Telegrm ID: @stackuserzeinab Can you txt me please?

Comment: Can I know which type of help you need.

Comment: The prefix addresses you have in the image link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the class name `.container-fluid` to something else as that is a bootstrap predefined class.

You can change the class name to anything else you want.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/mdrzqOM

Answer (score 0):

Add `.col` to `<div class="col-xs-12">`.

Is it possible, that you are using Bootstrap 4 while looking to Bootstrap 5 guide?

```css
/*======================   header  ======================*/

header .row {
  margin: 0;
}

header .row .col-xs-12 {
  padding: 0;
}

header .row .gen-nav-header {
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #e38d13;
}

header .row .gen-nav-header .container-fluid {
  width: 96%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  /*align-items: center;*/
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

header .row .gen-nav-header .container-fluid .right-svg {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

header .row .gen-nav-header .container-fluid .nike-svg {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <!-- ================  header  ============== -->
    <header>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-xs-12"> <!-- ← ADD .col HERE  ← -->
          <div class="gen-nav-header">
            <div class="container-fluid">

              <!------------------  right svg   ------------------->
              <div class="right-svg">
                <span class="hamburger-menu-svg">
                                <svg width="24px" height="24px" fill="#111" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                    <path d="M21 13H3c-.6 0-1-.4-1-1s.4-1 1-1h18c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1zm0-8H3c-.6 0-1-.4-1-1s.4-1 1-1h18c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1zm0 16H3c-.6 0-1-.4-1-1s.4-1 1-1h18c.6 0 1 .4 1 1s-.4 1-1 1z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                <span class="search-svg">
                                <svg class="pre-search-input-icon" fill="#111" height="30px" width="30px" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                    <path d="M21.71 20.29L18 16.61A9 9 0 1 0 16.61 18l3.68 3.68a1 1 0 0 0 1.42 0 1 1 0 0 0 0-1.39zM11 18a7 7 0 1 1 7-7 7 7 0 0 1-7 7z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
                <span class="shopping-svg">
                                <svg width="24px" height="24px" fill="#111" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                                    <path d="M16 7a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V3H9v3a1 1 0 0 1-2 0V3a2 2 0 0 1 2-2h6a2 2 0 0 1 2 2v3a1 1 0 0 1-1 1z"></path>
                                    <path d="M20 5H4a2 2 0 0 0-2 2v13a3 3 0 0 0 3 3h14a3 3 0 0 0 3-3V7a2 2 0 0 0-2-2zm0 15a1 1 0 0 1-1 1H5a1 1 0 0 1-1-1V7h16z"></path>
                                </svg>
                            </span>
              </div>
              <!-----------------   end right svg   ------------------->

              <span class="nike-svg">
                            <svg class="pre-logo-svg" height="60px" width="60px" fill="#111" viewBox="0 0 69 32">
                                <path d="M68.56 4L18.4 25.36Q12.16 28 7.92 28q-4.8 0-6.96-3.36-1.36-2.16-.8-5.48t2.96-7.08q2-3.04 6.56-8-1.6 2.56-2.24 5.28-1.2 5.12 2.16 7.52Q11.2 18 14 18q2.24 0 5.04-.72z"></path>
                            </svg>
                        </span>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

  </main>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap 3 in this project. This is the CDN: <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">